# Android Design application for only tablets

Tags: android

I am trying to develop android application only for tablets ,the problem is how can i design the layouts for different resolution and different SDK's.example tablets are officially supports from 3.0 but some tablets are available from 2.2 onwards ,please help me how can i implement.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: use wrapcontent and matchparent(fillparent) instead of giving density independent pixels for the views and viewgroups.that makes the App work for various versions of tablets and even normal mobiles.
Check this for more info : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

It works like this:

- Put the android support library jar in your libs folder
- Add jar to eclipse build path
- Extend FragmentActivity rather than Activity in all of your activities.
- Use density independant pixels
- follow tips on designing for different screen sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
- Follow the developer guides for fragments (used for tablets primarily): http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Here is a good tutorial as well (which includes references to the support library):
http://marakana.com/s/android_fragments_tutorial,1250/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link:
Visit http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/user-interface-design-android-apps

You will get a rough idea about the design patterns. I'll suggest for targeting tablet devices use layout-large and in the latest ADT plugin you have got drawable-xhdpi for the images and all. 
Don't use hard-coded width or height of the widget as this will create problems when you migrate from 7" to 8.9" or 10.1".

Better you use 9-patch images for the tablet version.

Answer (score 0):

- **SDK:**

Use 4.1 SDK and specify min SDK = 2.2. Eclipse will tell you where you use too new methods or classes and you will have to handle it in the code. For example:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
... 
} else {
...             
}
```

- **Layouts and screen sizes:**

Use different layout folders (by default it's "layout"). You can use layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge.

- BTW. **Always read Android Guide**:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)